# How can I get Flexbox positioning to work in Safari 10.0?

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

Before marking this question as a duplicate, please take a look at this JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/751cg8d1/10/

HTML:

```html
 <div class="opLandingContainer">
      <ul class="opWelcomeNavBar affix">
        <li class="opWelcomeNavBarLogo" >
          <a href="/">
            <img class="ui image" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li style="right: 0; position: absolute" class="opWelcomeNavBarItem nondropdown">
          <a style="padding-right: 0" href="/sign-up">Sign Up</a>
          <a href="/sign-in">Sign In</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.opWelcomeNavBarLogo {
    position:absolute;
    width:225px;
    display:inline-block;
 }
.opWelcomeNavBarLogo img {
    height: 68px;
}
@media(max-width:600px) {
    .opWelcomeNavBarLogo {
        width: 125px !important;
    }
    .opWelcomeNavBarLogo img {
        height: 38px !important;
    }
}
.opWelcomeNavBar.affix a {
    color:black;
}
.opWelcomeNavBar.affix {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.opWelcomeNavBar{
    border:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    height:90px;
    z-index:1;
    margin:0;
    position:fixed;
    list-style-type: none;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    /*border: 0 none;*/
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /*display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -moz-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;*/
}
.opWelcomeNavBar a:hover{
    color: #ababab;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.opWelcomeNavBar a {
    color:white;
    font-size:1.3em;
    text-decoration:none;
    height:50px;
    padding:15px;
    border:2px solid transparent;
}
```

The goal of this code is to vertically center some items in a container (in this case, some menu items in a top nav bar).

If you view the fiddle in Chrome, everything works correctly. However, in Safari 10, the items are not vertically centered. I have attempted to use every type of vendor prefix (which in this version of Safari shouldn't be necessary), but none of those changes seem to work. From what I have read, this version of Safari should fully support the flex positioning specification. I have also looked through the common flex bugs here: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs, but none of these seem to apply to what I am seeing in this example.

Correct View in Chrome:

[image: Correct View in Chrome]

Incorrect View in Safari 10:

[image]

Comment: I got the same in Safari 9, it is all Safari I think.

Comment: Why are you using `position: absolute;` on the flex children? Works fine if you remove that https://jsfiddle.net/751cg8d1/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're absolutely positioning flex items.

In a flex container, `position: absolute` removes items from the flex formatting context.

Just use flex properties to align your items. You don't need `position: absolute`.

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items

Comment: Wow, thank you. The absolute positioning was a remnant from older code which I must have missed. Any idea why the flex positioning overrides it in Chrome but not Safari?

Comment: The manner in which browsers handle absolutely-positioned flex children can differ: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/absolute-positioned-children

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `.opWelcomeNavBar a` rule and `height` and `display` properties.

It works on Safari.

But you have too much CSS for a small menu !

Prefer using `float` instead of `position` or [Bootstrap Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/)

```css
.opWelcomeNavBarLogo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 225px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.opWelcomeNavBarLogo img {
  height: 68px;
}

@media(max-width:600px) {
  .opWelcomeNavBarLogo {
    width: 125px !important;
  }
  .opWelcomeNavBarLogo img {
    height: 38px !important;
  }
}

.opWelcomeNavBar {
  border: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 90px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.opWelcomeNavBar.affix {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.opWelcomeNavBar a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.opWelcomeNavBar.affix a {
  color: black;
}

.opWelcomeNavBar a:hover {
  color: #ababab;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="opLandingContainer">
  <ul class="opWelcomeNavBar affix">
    <li class="opWelcomeNavBarLogo">
      <a href="/">
        <img class="ui image" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li style="right: 0; position: absolute;" class="opWelcomeNavBarItem nondropdown">
      <a href="/sign-up">Sign Up</a>
      <a href="/sign-in">Sign In</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

PS : `paddingRight` isn't CSS ! It is JS, use `padding-right` and prefer avoid `style` attribute.

PS2 : You can use Stackoverfow snippet and please clean your CSS before post !

Comment: Sorry for the messy CSS -- this is actually written in React, so I must have missed one or two style names.